# How to read every line in a file

Tags: python, file

so i have a txt file that i am opening. When I open it I want to read and print out every line in that file. My problem is that my code is only reading every other line. for ex. if my txt file contained the words

```
bob
cat
dog
bacon
```

it would only read and print

```
bob
dog
```

skipping the other two.

```
def main8():
    count = 1
    askName = input('Whats the name of the file your trying to see? ')
    infile = open(askName,'r')
    for row in infile:
        line = infile.readline()
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print(count,':', line, sep='\t')
        count += 1
    infile.close
main8()
```

Comment: You don't need `readline` inside the loop. The loop is reading the lines and putting them in the variable `row`. Just get rid of `line = infile.readline()` and make the loop `for line in infile:`

Comment: The point of iterating over file-like objects is that you don't need to call `readline` explicitly; the `__next__` method does it implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `for row in infile` iterates over the lines of the file. Then, `infile.readline()` reads the next line. You aren't using `row`, so you're throwing every other line away.

Replace the loop iterator with `line`, remove the `line = infile.readline()`, and you're good to go.

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code lies in the combination of using a for loop to iterate over the lines of the file and also using readline() within the loop. When you use a for loop to iterate over the lines of a file, you're already reading each line sequentially. Using readline() inside the loop effectively skips every other line because it's advancing the file pointer to the next line.

To fix this issue, you can simply remove the readline() line from your loop. Here's the corrected version of your code:

```py
def main8():
    count = 1
    askName = input('What\'s the name of the file you\'re trying to read? ')
    with open(askName, 'r') as infile:  # Using "with" ensures the file is properly closed
        for line in infile:  # Iterating directly over the lines of the file
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            print(count, ':', line, sep='\t')
            count += 1

main8()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a loop where you manually read lines from the file, use an infinite loop and check each call to `readline` for an empty string.

```
while True:
    line = infile.readline()
    if line == '':
        break
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    print(count,':', line, sep='\t')
    count += 1
```

The iterator protocol, as implemented by file-like objects, calls `readline` for you.

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    print(count,':', line, sep='\t')
    count += 1
```

---

You should also use a `with` statement to ensure the file is closed properly, and you can use `enumerate` to generate the line numbers for you.

```
def main8():
    askName = input('Whats the name of the file your trying to see? ')
    with open(askName,'r') as infile:
        for count, line in enumerate(infile, start=1):
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            print(count,':', line, sep='\t')

main8()
```